# How to user @Id in superClass By using @Embedable in another class in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have 2 Classes, one is `Student.class(Embedded)` and other is `CommonDetails.class(Embeddable)`. I want to create a table of students with fields of id, name, email and id as identifier.

But it's throwing this exception:

```
No identifier specified for entity: com.icore.mint.data.customer.service.usage.Student.
```

Is there any solution that I don't want to create the field `id` in `Student.class`. I want to use `id` from `CommonDetails.class.`

Below is the code.

**CommonDetails.class**

```
@Embeddable
public class CommonDetails implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String id;
    String name;
    String email;
    //Setters and Getters
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    //toString()
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CommonDetails [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ",
         email=" + email + "]";
    }
}//Class
```

**Student.class**

```
@Table
@Table(name="student")
public class Student implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    CommonDetails commonDetails;
    //Setters and Getters
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "name", column = @Column(name = 
    "name")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "email", column = @Column(name = 
    "email"))
    })
    public CommonDetails getCommonDetails() {
        return commonDetails;
    }
    public void setCommonDetails(CommonDetails commonDetails) {
        this.commonDetails = commonDetails;
    }
    //toString()
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [commonDetails=" + commonDetails + "]";
    }
}//Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for **`@EmbeddedId`** annotation.

Here is example from my project :

Class with `@Embeddable` annotation :

```
@Embeddable 
public class SetLogs implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Integer user_id;

    @Column(name="menu_id")
    private Integer menu_id; 

    @Column(name="logs_time")
    private Date logs_time;

}
```

Class with `@EmbeddedId` annotation :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="logs")
public class Logs implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private SetLogs setLogs;

    public SetLogs getSetLogs() {
        return setLogs;
    }

    public void setSetLogs(SetLogs setLogs) {
        this.setLogs = setLogs;
    }
}
```

You can also refer to this link http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-embeddedid-hibernate

Hope this will help you.

Comment: by using your code, it creates all fields as composite PK's .but i need  only one filed(id) as PK and other's(name,email)as normal fileds.